# Moving x,y position of all array objects every frame in actionscript 3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, duplicates

I have my code setup so that I have a movieclip in my library with a class called "block" being duplicated multiple times and added into an array like this:

```
function makeblock(e:Event){
newblock=new block;
newblock.x=10;
newblock.y=10;
addChild(newblock);
myarray[counter] = newblock; //adds a newblock object into array
counter += 1;
}
```

Then I have a loop with a currently primitive way of handling my problem:

```
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);
    function gameloop(evt:Event):void {
        if (moveright==true){
            myarray[0].x += 5;
            myarray[1].x += 5;
            myarray[2].x += 5
              -(and so on)-
```

My question is how can I change x,y values every frame for new objects duplicated into the array, along with the previous ones that were added. Of course with a more elegant way than writing it out myself... array[0].x += 5, array[1], array[2], array[3] etc.

Ideally I would like this to go up to 500 or more array objects for one array so obviously I don't want to be writing it out individually haha, I also need it to be consistent with performance so using a for loop or something to loop through the whole array and move each x += 5 wouldn't work would it? Anyway, if anyone has any ideas that'd be great!

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?  Is that going too slowly?  How are the items being drawn to the screen?  Also in a loop?  Or does AS3 draw arrays full of objects for you?

Comment: I haven't fully put in a for loop to test it that way yet but I'm thinking if I have multiple arrays with hundreds of objects to move it might take quite a performance hit running through each array in a loop. I was wondering if there was a way I hadn't thought of so I could dynamically create a variable or something for each object created. Then sort of get each one to update its x position every frame upon its creation.

Comment: Ah and items are drawn to the screen as soon as they are created, so I would create them off screen and then move them into the view basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to move 100 objects, you have to move them. No alternatives.

But what you can really do to save performance, is optimize the solution itself. A few cents from me:

- Of course the loop has to be applied in your case, managing 100+ assignments line by line is definitely not the right way to go. Although you gain nothing performance wise with just using a loop.
- Try grouping the objects. As I see above, you seem to be moving all those objects with similar increment. Group them all into larger movieclips (or [Sprites](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Sprite.html)) & move that instead.
- Learn [Blitting & caching](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/blitting_mc.html) methods to save a lot on performance, Or you would sooner or later hit on the road where your logic cannot be twisted anymore & performance will be a pain.
- Also, in extent of the previous step, do consider using [Sprite Sheets](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/actionscript_blitting.html) if you have multiple states of the same object.

Finally, I would also like to caution you to not waste time on micro optimizations & thinking about them.

Comment: Yes, agreed, thanks for all the input! I really just need to get more familiar with everything but your advice is greatly appreciated and I'll work on solving this tomorrow. I'll look into grouping the objects since I am moving all of them in the same direction at one time. I'll also look more into Blitting & caching and sprite sheets in the very near future.

Comment: Do remember to click the green tick beside an answer, if it helped you.

Comment: Yes yes, I wanted to try it out first before selecting an answer but yours covers pretty much everything so thank you for that. I'm very sure I'll be able to find a solution from your advice and will post back if I need help/find a solution that absolutely worked.

Comment: Just a quick update to say everything is working fine for me now, thank you very much for your help. I ended up putting the duplicated objects in a sprite container and moving the container as I needed. Works like a charm. I'll keep everything else you've said in mind for the future too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some container sprite and add the blocks to that on creation:

```
// Some init place
var blockContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(blockContainer);
```

Make the blocks:

```
function makeblock(e:Event){
    newblock=new block;
    newblock.x=10;
    newblock.y=10;
    // Add the block to the container
    blockContainer.addChild(newblock);
    myarray[counter] = newblock; //adds a newblock object into array
    counter += 1;
}
```

And the gameloop:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);

function gameloop(evt:Event):void {
    if (moveright==true){
         blockContainer.x += 5;
    }
    // etc...
}
```

This way you'll only have to move one object. Of course this method will only work so long as all the blocks need to move in the same direction. By the way, a for loop will work just as well - 500 iterations is nothing. The only performance issue will likely be just rendering and that will happen regardless of what method you choose, as you have to somehow move the blocks (in other words, performance here is not really the issue as you have to render the movement change, the only question is how you choose to implement the movement for your own coding convenience).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I will definitely look into what you've said and see if I can get it implemented sometime tomorrow. I am moving all the objects in the same direction so this may be a good option for me to try!

Comment: I wanted to pop back in and say I quickly tested out adding a container sprite and putting everything inside. It worked perfectly for what I needed done so thanks for that suggestion!